# Regex to edit text depending on number of occurrence of key word

Tags: r, regex

I'm grappling with a regex solution to the following problem: say, I have a series of strings that all contain a number of occurrences of the keyword `Appendix` or `appendix` like this:

```
text <- c("Appendix abc Appendix def appendix final",
          "blah blah Appendix abc Appendix finalissimo")
```

and I want to delete everything that follows the last occurrence of "Appendix" including the keyword itself to obtain the follwing **desired output**:

```
1 Appendix abc Appendix def
2 blah blah Appendix abc
```

I know (a) `tidyverse` solution(s) is/are possible (e.g., [Extract all text before the last occurrence of a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72339615/extract-all-text-before-the-last-occurrence-of-a-specific-word/72339826#72339826), but here I'm specifically interested in a **regex** solution. I've tried a number of such regex solutions but none seem to work. The one I thought most promising is this involving negative lookahead and backreference but it too does not produce the desired result:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, "(?i).*(?!(appendix).*\\1)")
```

I'd be grateful for advice why this solution does not work and for a regex solution that does work.

Comment: Maybe `str_replace(text, '(?i)(.*)\\bAppendix.*', '\\1')`? Or ``str_replace(text, '(?i)(.*)\\sAppendix.*', '\\1')`` if there is always a space before the word.

Comment: Thanks. This works well. Please post as an answer so I can accept it. Any advice why my `str_extract` solution does not work?

Comment: Your pattern matches any string and all of it.

Comment: You have mentioned that the expected output for `Appendix abc Appendix def appendix final` must be `Appendix abc Appendix def Appendix final`, the same text. Hence, I did not post an answer right away. And once you accept an answer with a working solution, I prefer not to add any more answers so as not to have the solution unaccepted.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize the typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex with lookahead logic here:

```r
text <- c("Appendix abc Appendix def appendix final",
          "blah blah Appendix abc Appendix finalissimo")
output <- sub("(?i)\\s+appendix(?!.*\\bappendix\\b).*", "", text, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "Appendix abc Appendix def" "blah blah Appendix abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub`. The first `.*` is greedy and will take everything until the last match of `Appendix.*`.

```
sub("(.*)Appendix.*", "\\1", text, TRUE)
#[1] "Appendix abc Appendix def " "blah blah Appendix abc "
```